# How to generate different values for each category using a trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have trained a model to predict values based on input categories. However, currently the predicted values are the same for each category.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import random
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Read the dataset using pandas
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

# Data Preprocessing
categories = data['category'].tolist()
values = data['value'].tolist()

# Tokenize categories
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(categories)
categories_tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(categories)

# Convert categories to one-hot vectors
num_categories = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
categories_one_hot = pad_sequences(categories_tokenized)

# Encode the target variable (values) as categorical
value_labels = np.unique(values)
value_mapping = {value: i for i, value in enumerate(value_labels)}
encoded_values = np.array([value_mapping[value] for value in values])

# Split data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    categories_one_hot, encoded_values, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)

# Build the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=num_categories, output_dim=64, input_length=categories_one_hot.shape[1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(value_labels), activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1000, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

# Save the model architecture and weights
model.save('model/iris')
model.save('model/iris.h5')


def generate_prediction(input_category, tokenizer, model, categories_one_hot, values):
    category_tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([input_category])
    category_one_hot = pad_sequences(category_tokenized, maxlen=categories_one_hot.shape[1])

    # Generate prediction
    prediction = model.predict(category_one_hot)
    predicted_label = np.argmax(prediction)

    # Map predicted label back to value
    value_labels = np.unique(values)
    value_mapping = {i: value for i, value in enumerate(value_labels)}
    predicted_value = value_mapping[predicted_label]

    return predicted_value


categories_test = list(set(data['category'].tolist()))

# Lists to store input categories and predicted values
keywords = []
prompts = []

for _ in range(10):
    # Randomly select an input category from the test set
    input_category = random.choice(categories_test)

    # Generate prediction for the input category
    predicted_value = generate_prediction(input_category, tokenizer, model, categories_one_hot, values)

    # Store the input category and predicted value
    keywords.append(input_category)
    prompts.append(predicted_value)

# Print the input categories and predicted values
for keyword, prompt in zip(keywords, prompts):
    print('Input category:', keyword, 'Predicted value:', prompt)
```

The dataset I'm using has categories and corresponding values like this:

```
category,value
color,red
color,blue
color,green
...
```

I would like to use the trained model to generate different values for each category.

I followed a standard approach to train and use the model for prediction. Here's what I did:

1. I loaded my dataset, which consists of categories and corresponding values.
2. I preprocessed the data by tokenizing the categories, converting them to one-hot vectors, and encoding the values as categorical labels.
3. I split the data into training and test sets.
4. I built a sequential model using TensorFlow's Keras API. The model includes an embedding layer, a flatten layer, and two dense layers with appropriate activation functions.
5. I compiled the model with suitable optimizer and loss function.
6. I trained the model using the training data and evaluated its performance on the test data.
7. Finally, I saved the trained model for future use.

To generate predictions, I wrote a function that takes an input category and uses the trained model to predict the corresponding value. However, the issue arises when I use this function repeatedly with different input categories. The predicted values turn out to be the same for all categories, which is not the expected behavior.

How to modify my code to ensure that the model generates different values for each category?

Answer (score 0):

try converting your categories to pd.get_dummies creating a column for each category then append the categories to the your tokenized data row by row then pad and feed into the network